# set constraints on dijit.form.ValidationTextBox

Tags: javascript, dojo

i am calling a function onblur .. that function call an ajax and that ajax get string ..

now i want if value in string is avail .. then text box  become red ..

my ajax code is

```
function ucheck(){
                dojo.xhrPost({
                    // The URL to request
                    url: "ucheck",
                    timeout :  3000 ,
                    content: {
                    username: dojo.byId("pref_id").value

                    },
                    // The method that handles the request's successful result
                    // Handle the response any way you'd like!
                    load: function(result) {
                        var fi=result;
                        document.getElementById('co').innerHTML=fi // this is print the value in lable


                    }
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you tried the following example and changed your code accordingly:

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/form/ValidationTextBox-tricks.html#dijit-form-validationtextbox-tricks